# How did Rhodey survive?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, iron-man-2008, war-machine

Colonel James "Rhodey" Rhodes was present during Stark's kidnapping in Marvel Studios' *Iron Man* (2008) - in fact, he was in the Humvee behind him (dubbed the "Hum-drumvee" by Stark just minutes before the attack). However, it seems all members present were killed during the attack. Rhodes later comes back to save Tony (indirectly) and says:

> How was the "Fun-vee"? Next time, you ride with me.

How did Rhodes survive the attack? Is there a canon MCU answer, or something in the comics?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Rhodey wasn't in the Humvee behind Stark's, at least not at the point that it was attacked.**

There appear to be four Humvees in immediate view as well as a Jeep. Humvee #1 is totally destroyed in the initial explosion. Stark is in Humvee #2 (of which all of the occupants apart from himself are killed or seriously injured). Humvee #3, which you assumed contains Rhodey, despite there being **no actual evidence of this**, is attacked, but at the point that it's assaulted and the crew die, there are only three soldiers present on screen, none of whom are dressed like Rhodey. Humvee #4 appears untouched in the background.

[image]

Possibly he was in the last Humvee or, like in the [original screenplay](https://www.screenwritersnetwork.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Iron-Man-Script.pdf), he had disembarked and was off chasing after baddies.

> TONY’S POV - OF JIMMY: as he’s stitched by a bouncing Betty
> mine. Now, running past, firing a .50 cal. machine gun is --
>
> USAF Lt. Colonel JAMES “RHODEY” RHODES. He looks in.
>
> **RHODEY:** *GET DOWN, TONY. GET THE --*
>
> [An EXPLOSION cuts him off. **Rhodey fires through the chaos,
> covering all directions, then advances into the murk.**]
>
> <sub><sup>[Iron Man - Original Screenplay](https://www.screenwritersnetwork.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Iron-Man-Script.pdf)</sup></sub>

Note that the [official junior novelisation](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Iron_Man:_The_Junior_Novel) we learn that the Ten Rings terrorists only hung around long enough to snatch Tony and leave. There was no effort made to mop up survivors.

> “Something’s not right,” Rhodey said.
>
> “It looks like a standard hit-and-run to me,” the general replied.
>
> “Sir, I’m telling you, this was a snatch-and-grab,” Rhodey insisted.
> **“As soon as they got what they wanted, they melted away—and what they
> wanted was Tony Stark.”**

Comment: "Now, running past, firing a .50 cal. machine gun..." Guess Rhodey got some of that super-soldier juice.

Comment: @ceejayoz Maybe not a full super-soldier, but Terrance Howards workout routine was not the same as say, Arnold Schwarzenegger.